# How to log output in bash and see it in the terminal at the same time?

Tags: linux, bash, logging, stdout, stderr

I have some scripts where I need to see the output **and** log the result to a file, with the simplest example being:

```
$ update-client > my.log
```

I want to be able to see the output of the command while it's running, but also have it logged to the file. I also log `stderr`, so I would want to be able to log the error stream while seeing it as well.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
update-client 2>&1 | tee my.log
```

2>&1 redirects standard error to standard output, and tee sends its standard input to standard output and the file.

Comment: You can also append the log file, as explained here, and do other stuffs with tee: http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/tee-command-examples/

Answer (score 7):

Just use tail to watch the file as it's updated. Background your original process by adding & after your above command After you execute the command above just use

```
$ tail -f my.log
```

It will continuously update. (note it won't tell you when the file has finished running so you can output something to the log to tell you it finished. Ctrl-c to exit tail)

Comment: wow tough crowd on this one. What exactly is wrong with this answer?

Comment: It's thousands of times worse than using `tee` in my opinion.

Comment: Requires I run process in background

Comment: Never knew about this Awesome tip!

Comment: I don't think this is really the answer I was looking for when I came here, but the knowledge of that command and its uses is useful. +1

Answer (score 7):

You can use the tee command for that:

```
command | tee /path/to/logfile
```

The equivelent without writing to the shell would be:

```
command > /path/to/logfile
```

If you want to append (>>) and show the output in the shell, use the -a option:

```
command | tee -a /path/to/logfile
```

Please note that the pipe will catch stdout only, errors to stderr are not processed by the pipe with tee. If you want to log errors (from stderr), use:

```
command 2>&1 | tee /path/to/logfile
```

This means: run command and redirect the stderr stream (2) to stdout (1). That will be passed to the pipe with the tee application.

*Learn about this at askubuntu site*

Comment: Can we tell tee to ignore `clear` and other control charater? Using any of these answer works great except if you do `cat /path/to/logfile` the clear command is reproduced.

Answer (score 4):

another option is to use block based output capture from within the script (not sure if that is the correct technical term).

Example

```
#!/bin/bash 
{
  echo "I will be sent to screen and file"
  ls ~
} 2>&1 | tee -a /tmp/logfile.log

echo "I will be sent to just terminal"
```

I like to have more control and flexibility - so I prefer this way.

Comment: This does not preserve the exit code, though: is there a way to do it?
I tried both `{` and `(` brackets, i..e if I do `exit 1` inside the brackets, the script still exits with 0.